# Java Printing Functions

Tags: java, printing

I need help writing the printing functions in this java application of another class.

The functions are with printAll I think is right and the other function is definitely wrong.

```
public void printAll() {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems from the given vendor, 
// in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void print(String vendor) {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    if (dictionary.getItem(SKU).getVendor() == vendor)
        System.out.println(tmp.toString());
}
```

The entire function I will write down below for the parts that are needed for this problem.

```
import data_structures.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ProductLookup {


DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary;
private int maxSize;

public ProductLookup(int maxSize, DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary) {
    this(maxSize);
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
}

// Constructor.  There is no argument-less constructor, or default size
public ProductLookup(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

// Adds a new StockItem to the dictionary
public void addItem(String SKU, StockItem item) {
    dictionary.insert(SKU,item);
}

// Returns the StockItem associated with the given SKU, if it is
// in the ProductLookup, null if it is not.
public StockItem getItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return null;
    return dictionary.getValue(SKU);
}

// Returns the retail price associated with the given SKU value.
// -.01 if the item is not in the dictionary
public float getRetail(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getRetail();
}

public float getCost(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getCost();
}

// Returns the description of the item, null if not in the dictionary.
public String getDescription(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return null;
    return getItem(SKU).getDescription();
}

// Deletes the StockItem associated with the SKU if it is
// in the ProductLookup.  Returns true if it was found and
// deleted, otherwise false.  
public boolean deleteItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return false;
    return dictionary.remove(SKU);
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems with their associated
// price, in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void printAll() {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems from the given vendor, 
// in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void print(String vendor) {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    if (dictionary.getItem(SKU).getVendor() == vendor)
        System.out.println(tmp.toString());
}

// An iterator of the SKU keys.
public Iterator<String> keys() {
    return dictionary.keys();
}

// An iterator of the StockItem values.    
public Iterator<StockItem> values() {
     return dictionary.values();
}
}
```

Since it was confusing without actually seeing DictionaryADT I will include it here.

```
package data_structures;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public interface DictionaryADT<K,V> {

// Returns true if the dictionary has an object identified by
// key in it, otherwise false.
public boolean contains(K key);

// Adds the given key/value pair to the dictionary.  Returns
// false if the dictionary is full, or if the key is a duplicate.
// Returns true if addition succeeded.
public boolean insert(K key, V value);

// Deletes the key/value pair identified by the key parameter.
// Returns true if the key/value pair was found and removed,
// otherwise false.
public boolean remove(K key);

// Returns the value associated with the parameter key.  Returns
// null if the key is not found or the dictionary is empty.
public V getValue(K key);

// Returns the key associated with the parameter value.  Returns
// null if the value is not found in the dictionary.  If more
// than one key exists that matches the given value, returns the
// first one found.
public K getKey(V value);

// Returns the number of key/value pairs currently stored
// in the dictionary
public int size();

// Returns true if the dictionary is at max capacity
public boolean isFull();

// Returns true if the dictionary is empty
public boolean isEmpty();

// Returns the Dictionary object to an empty state.
public void clear();

// Returns an Iterator of the keys in the dictionary, in ascending
// sorted order.  The iterator must be fail-fast.
public Iterator<K> keys();

// Returns an Iterator of the values in the dictionary.  The
// order of the values must match the order of the keys.
// The iterator must be fail-fast.
public Iterator<V> values();
}
```

Comment: What is that new keys() method and null in values() method().

Comment: Those aren't written, due to me not knowing what to put in there

Comment: What is DictionaryADT? Is that your own class which has some list inside to store the values.

Comment: DictionaryADT is a class filled with functions like insert, remove, contains, isEmpty, getValue, getKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DictionaryADT is a class with all the actual implementation, then you need to call

I believe you have Map inside DictionaryADT then, something like

```
public Collection<StockItem> values() {
    return dictionary.values(); 
}
```

to get the keys, Iterator is changed to Set

```
public Set<String> keys() {
    return dictionary.keySet(); // return Set, Please perform all the set opetations.
}
```

I believe this what you are looking for.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: I think that fixes my iterator so I will edit my iterators in the original post and could you help me with the print function

Comment: You have created the interface, But where are you storing your object. You need some kind of place to store your data. For instance, Map, List or Queue. Or you need implement your own logic to store and retrieve the data. For your understanding : Assume you are using DictionaryADT.insert("Key", new StockItem());, where do this value get stored in JVM. You have only declared only interface.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these methods make any sense:

```
// An iterator of the SKU keys.
public Iterator<String> keys() {
    return new ;
}

// An iterator of the StockItem values.    
public Iterator<StockItem> values() {
    return null;
}
```

The first won't compile, and the second instantly causes NPEs when invoked. Now, what is a `DictionaryADT`?  Does it implement `Map`?  If so, it has a `keySet` and `valueSet` method, which you should use. Perhaps you can replace it with `HashMap`.

You do not need the `toString` calls in `print` and `printAll`, though I would prefer to reserve `toString` for debugging and write a separate method.  However, why can't you use a foreach loop, assuming `DictionaryADT` implements `Map`:

```
public void printAll() {
    for (final StockItem item: dictionary.valueSet()) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Finally, use `equals` instead of `==` in your `print` method.   You can look up why.

Comment: Yeah I know about the iterators in hindsight I should have left them blank so it wou;dn't confuse anyone. DisctionaryADT doesn't implement Map. It is implemented into different functions such as Hastable and BST.